# Very slow aggregate on Pandas 2.0 dataframe with pyarrow as dtype_backend

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pyarrow, apache-arrow

Let's say I have the following dataframe:

| Code | Price |
| --- | --- |
| AA1 | 10 |
| AA1 | 20 |
| BB2 | 30 |

And I want to perform the following operation on it:

```
df.groupby("code").aggregate({
    "price": "sum"
})
```

I have tried playing with the new pyarrow dtypes introduced in Pandas 2.0 and I created 3 copies, and for each copy I measured execution time (average of 5 executions) of the operation above.

| Code column dtype | Price column dtype | Execution time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Object | float64 | 2.94 s |
| string[pyarrow] | double[pyarrow] | 49.5 s |
| string[pyarrow] | float64 | 1.11 s |

Can anyone explain why applying an aggregate function on a column with double pyarrow dtype is so slow compared to the standard numpy float64 dtype?

Comment: The last stable pandas version is 1.5.3. The version 2.0.0 is the first release candidate. If you found an issue, create a ticket on [github](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues) or search if it's not already exist.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/52070

Looks like groupby for arrow isn't implemented yet - so there's likely a arrow -> numpy happening internally leading to a loss of performance.